# Use the definition to find $\int_0^2f(x)dx$ where $f (x )=\cases{ 1,&$x \ne 1$\\2,& $x = 1$}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

> Use the definition to find $\int_0^2f(x)dx$ where $f (x )=\cases{ 1,&$x \ne 1$\\2,& $x = 1$}$

I am stuck with this question, we studying Riemann integration, in my mind  I can do the integral over $[0,1] +[1,2] =[0,2]$

the  question is how  I set up the integral, I mean i understand $f (x )=\cases{ 1,&$x \ne 1$\\2,& $x = 1$}$., so  the first integral $\int_0^1 f(x) dx=x ,  1-0 =1$, second integral $\int_1^2 f(x) dx= 2-1=1$, so $\int_0^2 f(x)dx=1+1=2$?

Comment: This Q is hard to read. Hence, consider to visit [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for format improvement.

Comment: what's your definition of an integral? is it Riemann integration? Perhaps state the definition and then work from there?

Comment: The jump at $x=1$ adds no area to the function, so you can just integrate $\int_0^2 f(x)dx=\int_0^2dx$

Comment: What does “use the definition to …” mean?

Comment: It's not pair wise addition, it's called splitting into disjoint intervals, so use  ```\cup```. $$(0,1)\cup (1,2)=(0,2)\setminus \{1\}$$

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523634/two-functions-differing-at-finitely-many-points-have-the-same-riemann-integral) more general situation. Consider $g(x)=1$ for all $x$. $g$ and $f$ differ only at one point.